# Why are 'chown' and 'chgrp' not working?

Tags: linux, permissions, ubuntu-10.10

I've just installed Ubuntu 10.10 AMD-64 and mounted several partitions into `/mnt/` directory. Now I want to be able to perform operations on those partitions without limitations. I'm trying to change the owner and group but it doesn't work. I'm typing `sudo chown username filename` to perform the operations.

Comment: What error are you getting if any?

Comment: No error, simply no effect from the commands.

Comment: Are you getting prompted for the password at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What filesystems are those partitions using? FAT32, ext3, ...?

- Such filesystems as FAT do not support file ownership *at all*. You have to specify the default owner in mount options, or let GNOME/udisks handle the mounting.
- NTFS *does* support file ownership and ACLs, but I'm not sure if this feature is enabled in the ntfs-3g version that comes with Ubuntu.

Comment: It's NTFS and it's actually not enabled. Thank you.